# Can node.js listen on UNIX socket?

Tags: node.js

Can `node.js` listen on UNIX socket? I did not find any documentation regarding this. I only saw the possibility of listening on a dedicated port.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes. It's in the documentation.

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_backlog_callback

Comment: For the http module https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback

Answer (score 87):

To listen for incoming connections in node.js you want to use the [net.server](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) class.

The standard way of creating an instance of this class is with the `net.createServer(...)` function. Once you have an instance of this class you use the `server.listen(...)` function to tell the server where to actually listen.

If the first argument to listen is a number then nodejs will listen on a TCP/IP socket with that port number. However, if the first argument to listen is a string, then the server object will listen on a Unix socket at that path.

```
var net = require('net');

// This server listens on a Unix socket at /var/run/mysocket
var unixServer = net.createServer(function(client) {
    // Do something with the client connection
});
unixServer.listen('/var/run/mysocket');

// This server listens on TCP/IP port 1234
var tcpServer = net.createServer(function(client) {
    // Do something with the client connection
});
tcpServer.listen(1234);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use child process and socket.io to have a client connection that communicates with a server side application using this method? would a new port/path be needed in order to maintain a 1 to 1 client to app relationship?

Comment: For those wondering, you can do this with [express 4.x](https://expressjs.com) too! Because `app.listen` is [basically a helper function](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen), doing `app.listen("/var/run/mysocket")` is just as valid.

Comment: it seems that the socket file remains after the execution exits. Is there a better way for node to auto remove the sock file when it exits?

Comment: @ggedde you could add a process exit listener and then delete the socket file in that

Comment: @ggedde I also have this problem. Putting `fs.unlinkSync(socketPath);` before the `listen()` call worked for me.

Comment: @electrovir and gitaarik, can you provide examples. So far adding the fs.unlinkSync(socketPath); before the listen only removes the socket before a start, but does not remove it on process end. I have also been looking into process exit listener, but can't find any good examples.  Thanks

Comment: @ggedde I created a package back in the day to help with adding process exit listeners: https://www.npmjs.com/package/catch-exit The relevant source code for attaching listeners is here: https://github.com/electrovir/catch-exit/blob/master/src/index.ts#L223-L249