# Socket communication between c++ Client and node.js Server

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets

I want to make my c++ app (running on Linux system) to connect and send data to node.server via socket.

I tried to implement small sample app by using socket.io library (https://github.com/uning/socket.io-client-cpp), but doesnt helping me to achieve my goal.

Any  guidance on this or alternative to do something like this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843195/nodejs-communicate-with-c-program)

Comment: OK, so you've said what you want. Now where's the question?

Comment: @freakish : Opps.. In hurry forgot to add other information... I have edited question...!!

Comment: @PeterWood : Already tried that, Connection is done between two sockets(c++ client socket & node.js server socket), but no data transfer is not happening..!!

Comment: @Mayur Can you make it work between two c++ clients?

Comment: @PeterWood: I have taken client file from already working sample client/server socket application.

Comment: Sample found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841942/communicating-between-nodejs-and-c-using-node-ipc-and-unix-sockets