# node.js-http: listen on local unix pipe/socket

Tags: node.js, http, sockets, websocket, pipe

Is there a possibility to listen a node.js-http server natively on a local unix pipe/socket? (e. g. /var/tmp/http.sock). I want to use it in combination with [WebSockets](http://einaros.github.com/ws/) and a reverse proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can node.js listen on UNIX socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045614/can-node-js-listen-on-unix-socket)

Comment: I know that node.js can listen on unix pipes. But my question is if this is also possible for the http module. I don't want to implement it by myself if there's a solution available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because http is based on net, you can use the same options that the net module has.  In fact, the [http docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback) explicitly say that you can listen on a unix socket.

```
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen('/var/tmp/http.sock');
```

Comment: Neat trick! Now how do you get Firefox to connect to that socket and send an HTTP request? Just kidding.

Comment: Does it mean that there will be no traversal to the network card?