# Node.js: Send GET request via unix socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, go, unix-socket

I am new to the *node.js*. I am trying to setup the client server connection using unix socket, where my client request would be in *node.js* and server running in the background would be in go.

Client side Code:

```
    var request = require('request');

    request('http://unix:/tmp/static0.sock:/volumes/list', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        } else {
            console.log("In else part of the receiver" + response.statusCode + body)
        }
    }


})
```

When I try to communicate with the server written in go it is shows the `HTTP  error: 400 Bad Request: malformed Host header'`

The same works with:

```
curl -X GET --unix-socket /tmp/static0.sock http://:/volumes/list
```

Not sure what is wrong with my request. Do we need to send the headers? I expecting the JSON response.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_backlog_callback

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045614/can-node-js-listen-on-unix-socket

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To accomplish this without using the request module, try the following:

```
const http = require('http');

const options = {
  socketPath: '/tmp/static0.sock',
  path: '/volumes/list',
};

const callback = res => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', data => console.log(data));
  res.on('error', data => console.error(data));
};

const clientRequest = http.request(options, callback);
clientRequest.end();
```

Comment: const options = {
  socketPath: '/tmp/static0.sock',
  path: '/volumes/list',
}; this was the crucial part which i had missed

Comment: How to get the data from within the success response ?

Answer (score -6):

Consider the following example :

client side code : 
Also you can do socket connection in some code :

```js
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
  socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com' , {'force new connection':true});
  socket.on('event', function(){
    // code to execute
  });
</script>
```

server side code in nodejs : 
For this install npm, then 
1)npm init 
2)npm install --save express
3)npm insatll --save socket

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socket = null;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(soc) {
  socket = soc;
  console.log('socket connected');
});


app.get('/test', function(request, response) {
  var message = "Hello world";
  socket.emit('event', message);
  response.writeHead(200);
  reponse.write(message);
  reponse.end();
});

var server = app.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

You can hit this from browser a check